# Plot 3d graph with date axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, plotly

I want to plot 3D graph, where my data have the following structure

```
   date         0.25 0.5    0.75   1     1.25   1.5    1.75  2      2.25  2.5    2.75 
   2011-01-04   4.75  4.82   4.87  4.92   4.95  4.98   5.01  5.04   5.07  5.09   5.12
   2011-02-01   4.74  4.77   4.8   4.81   4.82  4.83   4.84  4.85   4.87  4.9    4.93
```

That means that one axis should displays date, one maturities ( 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75,  2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75) and one interest rates (4.75,  4.82,   4.87,  4.92,   4.95,...).

I tried to use the following code

```
graph3D <- wireframe(value ~ variable*date, data, 
                                       xlab = "Maturity",
                                       ylab = "Date",
                                      zlab = list("Interest rate (%)", rot = 90),
                                         col.regions = my.palette,
                                         cuts = 6,
                                  
                                        drape = TRUE,scales = list(arrows=FALSE, cex=.55, tick.number = 10, z = list(arrows=F), 
                                                                   distance =c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)))
```

But I got the following error: Error in UseMethod("wireframe") :
no applicable method for 'wireframe' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide your data with `dput()`?